# Hide parent thead if ALL tr in tbody are hidden display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I need your help:

The problem:

I have a select filter for my table. 
The filter hides the tr rows of the tbody if the value is not the same. The table-header still show.

The question:

If the select filter hides (display:none; ?) ALL tr of the tbody, the thead should also hide.

The Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name='kurs']").click(function() {
        $('tbody').each(function(){
            if ($(this).find("tr:hidden")) {
                $(this).closest(thead).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to hide the entire table, if no `tr` are visible?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There's probably more than one `tbody` in the table.

Comment: @Teemu: Even so, if they're all hidden, there isn't much of a difference between hiding the thead and the entire table, unless there's a tfoot that shouldn't be hidden for some reason (probably unlikely).

Comment: Hi! thead or complete entire table - both would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$('tbody').each(function(){
    if ($(this).has("> tr:visible").length === 0){
        $(this).closest('table').hide();
    }
});
```

It checks for visible `tr`s in the `tbody`, if there isn't any the `table` is hidden.

Comment: I didn't realize `.has()` didn't return a boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

This will also do :

```
$(this).parent().find("thead").hide();
```

Sample code :

```js
function hide() {

$('tbody').each(function(){  
  if($(this).not("tr:hidden").length=1)
    {      
      $(this).parent().find("thead").hide();
    }
});
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Table
<table border='1'>
<thead>  
  <tr><td>H1</td><td>H2</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr style='display:none'><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr style='display:none'><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr style='display:none'><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr style='display:none'><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<button onClick='hide()'>Hide</button>
```

Comment: This code kills all theads. I got 4 differet tables on one page. Also the tbody with only 1 hidden tr loose the thead.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqomwpfn/9/) and see if that's what you want.

When the select changes, it filters the rows. I've done something that might or might not be as the filtering method you may have. The important thing is the part that closes the thead when there's no rows.

```
$("#filter").change(function () {// Select changes and filters rows of the different tables.
    var class_to_filter = "." + $(this).val();// I'm accessing rows by class in order to close them, you may access them using some other method.

    $.each($(class_to_filter), function (i, item) {// For each one of them, close and check if you have to close thead as well.
        var $tr = $(item).closest('tr'),
            $tbody = $tr.closest('tbody'),
            $thead = $tbody.siblings('thead'),
            numOfVisibleRows;

        $tr.hide();// Hide row.
        numOfVisibleRows = $('tr:visible', $tbody).length;// Number of sibling rows visible.

        if (!numOfVisibleRows) {// if 0, hide thead.
            $thead.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.